# Selection of rows providing a specific condition in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count, case

I want to create a query like this:
For student_name, if the number of grade=0 and grade=1 students is equal, let's not select this person, but if the number of grade=0 and grade=1 students is different, let's select this person. In the query I will use for my example, Jack will not be selected, everyone else will be selected.

```
CREATE TABLE student
(
student_name VARCHAR(50),
grade CHAR(1)
)

INSERT INTO student
SELECT 'Jack', '0' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Jack', '0' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Jack', '0' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Jack', '1' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Jack', '1' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Jack', '1' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Rose', '0' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Rose', '0' UNION ALL
SELECT 'John', '1' UNION ALL
SELECT 'John', '1' UNION ALL
SELECT 'John', '1' UNION ALL
SELECT 'John', '1' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Dave', '1' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Dave', '1' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Chris', '0'

select * from student
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation and set the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT student_name
FROM student
GROUP BY student_name
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN grade = '0' THEN 1 END) <> COUNT(CASE WHEN grade = '1' THEN 1 END);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/p9YmTHBk).

Comment: "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 30
Incorrect syntax near ')'. "
i got this error. I am using sql server management studio. could it be related to that?

Comment: @BugraVarol why did you tag the question with SQLite if you are using SQL Server? See my edited answer.

Comment: I'm new to sql. I didn't know there was a difference between SQLite and sql server management codes. the solution worked. thanks.